# Refresh fragment instead of main activity

Tags: java, android, json, android-activity, swipe

I'm trying to implement the "swipe to refresh" in my fragment. I did it by inserting a timer in my main activity, by using the Timer class, which refresh, but I would like to improve it by implementing a function directly inside the fragment itself. This is the code:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public HomeFragment() {
    }

    public static HomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rc_view);
        loadMovie();

        return view;
    }


    private void loadMovie() {
        ApiService apiService = ApiBuilder.getClient(getContext()).create(ApiService.class);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        Call<MovieResponse> call = apiService.getDiscover(BuildConfig.API_KEY,Values.LANGUAGE,Values.SORT_BY[0], Values.ADULT, Values.GENRE[1], Values.PAGE[0]);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<MovieResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MovieResponse>call, Response<MovieResponse> response) {
                final List<MovieModel> movies = response.body().getResults();
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new MoviesAdapter(movies, R.layout.content_main, getContext()));
                recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
                    GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(), new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e){
                            return true;
                        }
                    });

                    @Override
                    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
                        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                        if (child != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)){
                            int position = rv.getChildAdapterPosition(child);
                            Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), DetailActivity.class);
                            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            i.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_TITLE, movies.get(position).getTitle());
                            i.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_OVERVIEW, movies.get(position).getOverview());
                            i.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_TIME, movies.get(position).getReleaseDate());
                            i.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_POSTER, movies.get(position).getPosterPath());
                            i.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, movies.get(position).getOriginalLanguage());
                            try{
                                List<Integer> genr = movies.get(position).getGenreIds();
                                i.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_GENRES, genr.toString());
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            getContext().startActivity(i);
                        }
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

                    }
                });
                if (movies != null ){

                    MovieModel firstMovie = movies.get(0);
                    if(firstMovie != null) {
                        Log.i("TAG", firstMovie.getTitle());
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MovieResponse>call, Throwable t) {
            }
        });
    }

}
```

This is the Timer I implemented in the main activity, which I want to remove:

```
TimerTask timertask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, TimerService.class));
                }
            });
        }
    };
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(timertask, 0, 10*SECONDS);
```

EDIT:
I updated my code by implementing the SwipeRefreshLayout inside the onCreate method but it still doesn't works:

```
mPullToRefresh = view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_list);
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    mPullToRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    loadMovie(); //load your moview from here
                    mPullToRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
```

This is my fragment layout updated:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Movies"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_20ssp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:text="Action"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/_150sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/rc_view"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: if you mean swiping down to refresh then this is how you do it :
https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't works, I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Layout to implement the functionality.

Put this in your fragment xml file:-

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Now in your Fragment:-

1) do the

```
SwipeRefreshLayout mPullToRefresh = view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_list)
```

2) then,

```
mPullToRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        loadMovie(); //load your moview from here 
                        mPullToRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
```

Please Up-Vote If Found Useful.

Comment: I implemented it but it doesn't works. I updated the question with the new code.

Comment: You have to call the method inside onActivityCreated() method of your fragment